# Help with Javascript Link Replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, wordpress, href

I'm trying to finish off a webapp version of my website. I'm really close, but the only thing I'm having trouble with is converting the a href's to javascript links (so that articles open w/in the app and not in Mobile Safari). I thought I'd found a simple script to help me out, but it turns out that script also messes with my comments plugin (Disqus). I'll post the script below, but is there any way I can have the script convert all links *except* those in the div "disqus_thread"?
I researched possible alternatives, but the only solution I could find was to use the script and specify all the other divs. Hopefully someone here can help me out :P 
Thanks,
Matt

```
   <script>
     var a=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
     for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
     {
     a[i].onclick=function()
     {
     window.location=this.getAttribute("href");
     return false
     }
     }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why would you do this. Because you are setting href property of anchor to `window.location` which anyways will be done by anchor's defualt behavior.

If you want to select all the anchor except those inside `disqus_thread` and execute your logic you can try this. Make sure you include `jQuery` library into your page.

```
$(":not(#disqus_thread)").find("a").click(function(){
   window.location.href = this.href;
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have jQuery included in the header but for some reason the same problem keeps occurring (tap to write comment in Disqus and I'm redirected to "thepageurl/null". The original script

Comment: Disqus is a commenting system where the comments are remotely served. The plugin calls the Disqus comments instead of your theme's/Wordpress's default system and plops itself in its own div, "disqus_thread."

Comment: Yep (Fill Text So I Can Comment :P)